# PHP usage object after creating

Tags: php, scope

I am creating object from the class, in this way :

```
// ##### function.php #####

class Test{
   function hello(){
      echo "Hello World";
   }
}

// ##### index.php #####

include 'function.php';

$test = new Test();
$test->hello();
include 'file2.php';

// ##### file2.php #####

$test->hello(); // This line is not working !!!
```

And 'index.php' is my index page and I am including for index file content from "files2.php". Problem is when I want to use "`$test`" object in "file2.php", I cannot get access to "`$test->hello()`". But when I create again new object from "`Test()`" class in "file2.php" than I can get access "`$test->hello()`".
I don't want to re-create the same object in including file, what can I do in this case.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there anything in your file2.php that changes $test in any way?

Comment: No, just I need to use this object's methods in child file.

Comment: Your sample code should work perfectly well; do you get any error (or anything written to your logs) when trying to execute `$test->hello()` in file2.php?

Comment: There is no error, $test variable I can see in file2.php but I cannot get this object's methods

Comment: In standard PHP, your usage should be 100% valid, are you testing with the exact files you're showing us above?

Comment: yes the same file structure. But index.php is in root folder and file2.php is in root/pages/

Comment: Unable to recreate the problem, I get "Hello World" echoed twice when I copy paste your files from the question and run it myself. Are you including the correct file2.php from `pages`?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax looks wrong. When I declared the class like this:

`enter code here// ##### function.php #####`

```
class Test { //not class Test()
function hello(){
      echo "Hello World";
   }
}
```

Everything else works as written.

Note that you forgot a semicolon on the last line:
`include 'file2.php';`

Comment: sorry for mistakes I edited, but in my source code everything is correct, but I don't know why child file cannot use parent file object?

Comment: then nothing is wrong with your code. I assume you have each file starting out with `<?php`? Can you report the exact error you get?

Comment: When I create object in index.php like this " $test = new Test(); " I can get access all methods in this object in index.php but when I want to get access to $test object in file2.php I can see $test variable but I cannot get methods.

Comment: not the line triggering the error, the actual error reported by php